# Why my delete function is not returning on page array after I delete element from it

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Below is the delete function which is working, it takes an argument and deletes the element with the index in the argument.

Setitem is a useState hook and is defined like this
when we click the on add list is added to item array

```
 const listofitem = () => {
    setitems((e) => {
      return [...e, list];
    });
  };
```

This function is working.

```
 const deleteItems = (e) => {
setitems((e1)=> {
  return e1.filter( (er, index)=> {
    return index!=e;
 });
});
```

}

Why is this not working the splice method is working fine.

```
const deleteItems = (e) => {
    items.splice(e-1, 1);
    setitems((e1)=>{
      return e1;
    })
  };
```

here is the code sandbox for the same, the function is working in this. But I want to know why the other is not working.

https://codesandbox.io/s/old-wood-cbnq86?file=/src/App.js:0-1169

Comment: splice mutates the original array and react has no clue if its changed .... so it doesn't work

Comment: Without looking at the code I can see a flaw in implementation. Splice mutates the original variable - items. So setItems would not trigger a change for items, therefore React would not know to re-render. I suggest doing items.slice().splice. Slice, will essentially detach the original items array into a new cloned array.

Comment: I know it mutates that's why I was trying to return it, and it is wrong how can I do so? The first one is working.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I got it to work, in your example you try to mutate the state directly and then not really set the state. If you want to use the state on setState you need to mutate what you call `e1`.
However you have some issues with your codesandbox that will trigger the function more than once sometimes

```
setitems((e1) => {
      e1.splice(e, 1);
      return [...e1];
    });
```

Edit author updated question, this is not longer relevant.
In the first deleteItems function you never use `e` which I assume is the index you want to delete.

```
const deleteItems = (deleteIndex) => {
    setitems((list)=> list.filter((_, index)=> index !== deleteIndex));
};
```

Comment: The first one os working, can you tell me how to fix the second one?

Comment: Yeah notice that you updated your code

Comment: So how I will do?